# Always on or fail over cluster in SP 2016 why?

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, sharepoint-on-prem, database-server, failover

I have a task to install SP 2016 farm 2 DB server, 2 wfe and app server! The 2 database in one Data center,

Which installation type should I use for database server, always on or fail over cluster, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AlwaysOn Availability Groups do not require the use of shared storage (which is typically expensive, and can provide a single point of failure) and failover from the primary to the secondary replica can be almost instant.

We have an active/active configuration using multiple AlwaysOn Availability Groups which allows us to spread the load across multiple servers. You can also configure read-only access for a secondary replica, so things like reports and backups can be running on the non-active node for an Availability Group, thus not affecting your primary replica which is used for standard read/write access.

Answer (score 1):

As per experience & various recommendations, i will go with AlwaysOn. Main advantage i am seeing here apart from others is, you can control the AO within sharepoint using the powershell as they are available.

You can see the commands here: [SharePoint Database Availability Group Cmdlets](https://thesharepointfarm.com/2014/05/sharepoint-database-availability-group-cmdlets/)
Read the following articles: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/configure-an-alwayson-availability-group